# Add hours to a time string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this `3:35 PM - 5:25 PM`. I am trying to write two functions `getStartTime(times)` and `getEndTime(times)` which return the start and end times in 24 hour clock format, i.e. in the above case it would return `15:35` and `17:25`. So far I have a working `getStartTime(times)`:

```
function getStartTime(times){
  var spaceSplit=times.split(" ");
  var colonSplit=times.split(":");
  if(s.search("PM")!=-1&&colonSplit[0]<12){
      return String(Number(colonSplit[0])+12)+":"+colonSplit[1].substring(0,2);
  }
  return spaceSplit[0];
}
```

However, it is ugly and I am not sure how to do the `getEndTime(times)`. Anyone know an elegant way to do both of these functions? Note that the string will always be in that format (although the hours could be two digits).

Comment: Search for "12 hour to 24 hour conversion" or something similar, then just split the string and convert each time.

Comment: If this works for the first time, why not just split the string on " - " and then send the two parts through this function one at a time

Comment: If it's absolutely in this format all the time you could use this regex pattern http://regexr.com/3b11b  - the substitutions $1 is start time, $2 is AM or PM, $3 is end time, $4 is AM or PM

Comment: @Steve good call that works fine.

Comment: You could make a class that handles all the cases. The start/end time will be class variables and it will also store info about am/pm etc. It can also  have an option to define the format of the date that will act as an input. This would be reusable and safer as it would have some checks about the format etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getStartTime(times)
   {
    var start_time = times.split("-")[0].trim();
    var res = start_time.split(" ");
    var hh = res[0].split(":")[0];
    var mm = res[0].split(":")[1];

    if( res[1]== "PM" && hh !="12")
    {
        hh = +hh + 12;
    }

    else if(hh==12 && res[1] == "AM")
    {
        hh = "00";
    }

    return(hh+":"+mm);
    }

function getEndTime(times)
{
    var end_time = times.split("-")[0].trim();
    var res = end_time.split(" ");
    var hh = res[0].split(":")[0];
    var mm = res[0].split(":")[1];

    if( res[1]== "PM" && hh !="12")
    {
        hh = +hh + 12;
    }

    else if(hh==12 && res[1] == "AM")
    {
        hh = "00";
    }


    return(hh+":"+mm);
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct conversion, you end up with 24:01 on 12:01 PM which is actually 0:01

Comment: @maraca 12:01 PM it should be 12:00 but for 12:01 AM it should be 00:01

Comment: right, thanks, corrected my solution, the only difference regarding the output is that you have format hh:mm and I have h:mm

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with regex:

```
var t = '3:35 PM - 5:25 PM';
console.log(getTimes(t));

function getTimes(timeString) {
  var matches = /^([1-9]|1[0-2])(:[0-5][0-9]) ([AP])M - ([1-9]|1[0-2])(:[0-5][0-9]) ([AP])M$/.exec(timeString);
  return [parseInt(matches[1]) % 12 + (matches[3] == 'A' ? 0 : 12) + matches[2],
          parseInt(matches[4]) % 12 + (matches[6] == 'A' ? 0 : 12) + matches[5]];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p5xzwuch/1/

Edit: You can match the `:` in the same group with the minutes, then you don't have to insert it manually ("corrected"). It just shows another way, if you don't know the number of whitespaces then you might have to modify a little and it is probably not the fastest way. The good thing about using regex is you can first see if it matches and only then return the result as shown, otherwise you can handle the error.